# Eth2.0 confirmation policy

Tags: consensus, confirmations

In bitcoin a transaction is considered confirmed after 6 blocks.
I read that a block is finalized after 2 epochs, but I've seen that  some people suggest to wait 12/15 blocks.

Why is that?

Is a transaction really confirmed after this blocks?

How can a transaction can be reverted for a malevolent player?